# Area of a spherical cap

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

> [image]

As picture above, although it is ugly, but the red ball is  a sphere with radial $r$ , i.e 
$$\{(x,y,z)\in R^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2\},$$  and the green is a spherical neighbourhood of North pole with radial $0<\delta\leq r$.

I want to calculate the area of green spherical neighbourhood.

Consider the coordinate of half-sphere 
$$
u:(x,y)\rightarrow (x,y,\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}).
$$
Then I have 
$$
u_x=(1,0,\frac{-x}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}})~~~u_y=(0,1,\frac{-y}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}}),
$$
Hence
$$
g_{11}=\frac{r^2-y^2}{r^2-x^2-y^2} ~~~ g_{12}=\frac{xy}{r^2-x^2-y^2} ~~~ 
g_{22}=\frac{r^2-x^2}{r^2-x^2-y^2}  \\
\det(g)=\frac{r^2}{r^2-x^2-y^2}
$$
Finally the area is 
$$
S  =\int\int_{x^2+y^2\le \delta ^2}  \frac{r^2}{r^2-x^2-y^2}  dx dy  \\
 = \int_0^\delta\int_{x^2+y^2=t^2}  \frac{r^2}{r^2-x^2-y^2}  dx dy dt   \\
 = \int_0^\delta \frac{2\pi r^2 t}{r^2-t^2} dt  
= -2\pi r\ln \frac{\sqrt{r^2-\delta^2}}{r}.
$$
But obviously, it is not right. Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you forgot to take the square-root of $|\det(g)|$. The area of the spherical cap is given by
$$\iint_{x^2+y^2\le \delta^2}  \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}}  dx dy
=2\pi r^2\int_{\rho=0}^{\delta/r}  \frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}  d\rho =2\pi rh.$$
where $h=r-\sqrt{r^2-\delta^2}$ is the height of the cap.

Comment: I’m too pressed for time to check, but as I recall, the answer is much more satisfying when you specify the radius as an angle, just as you specify the length of a geodesic as an angle.

Comment: Thanks, I calculate it again. I think you are right.